# Every time I close terminal rails defaults back to 2.3.5 from 3.0.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rvm

I'm going through the rails by example tutorial.

Its seems that every time I close terminal rails defaults back to 2.3.5 & I have to go through the process of installing 3.0.3 every time I open the terminal?

I installed rails using: $ [sudo] gem install rails --version 3.0.3

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? I've tried googling around and searching stack to no avail.

Comment: Funky. What does `gem list` output when you open a given terminal session, and how are you trying to invoke Rails? I bet 3.0.3 is still installed, but 2.3.5 is the default. Consider [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)'s gemsets as a nice long-term solution to these sorts of issues :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling the rails gem:

```
gem uninstall rails
```

If you are prompted to select a version, select 2.3.5 and leave the 3.0.3 version intact.

P.S: Are you using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)?  If not, I would highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks Pan. Yeh I'm using RVM. So your saying I should uninstall the rails gem, if I'm asked to select a version choose 2.3.5 & if not just uninstall and then re-install 3.0.3?

Comment: That's correct. If you want to play it safe, simply uninstall all rails gems and then only re-install the 3.0.3 one.

Comment: Another thing you can do to ensure you are in the correct RVM ruby version is to type "rvm 1.9.2" or "rvm 1.8.7" depending on your ruby version.  If you switch ruby versions often then you may end up having different versions of rails installed under the different ruby versions.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is almost-assuredly [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) interpreting 2.3.5 as your default rails version in your default gem set. I ran into this problem myself when first experimenting with RVM. Try this:

```
rvm --default use 1.9.2 (or whatever you want your default ruby interpreter to be)
rvm gemset create rails-3.0.3
rvm use 1.9.2@arails-3.0.3 --default
gem install rails
```

That will:

- Set your default ruby interpreter to the desired ruby version
- Create a gemset for your Rails 3.0.3 install and make it your default gemset
- Install rails

Once you close the terminal and open it back up, it'll load RVM's defaults, putting you back on Rails 3.0.3 again.

Comment: I am doing this, however, rubygems installs me the rails 4.0.0 version, even when I specify it to be rails 3.2.6, any comment on this?

Comment: @Francisco That's an issue unrelated to this question/answer. However, in an effort to help: How are you specifying v3.2.6?

Comment: @Shaun Hi, though the problem is now solved, let me tell you the way I specified the rails version was using the command `gem install rails -v 3.2.6`

PD: Why is this issue unrelated to the Q&A? As you suggested in your answer, creating that gemset would install rails 3.0.3, but it didn't worked for me, and therefore I asked you about.

PD2: Thanks!

Comment: @Francisco This issue was about rails defaulting to an installed version of Rails other than the one that was desired. You were describing that the wrong version was installing, which is a different issue with different root causes. :)

Comment: @Shaun Ok, got it. I supposed it has to do with StackOverflow rules, right?

Comment: @Francisco It's more a suggestion that re-asking your question as a normal question (since it's unrelated) would probably get your answer a lot faster since it would be more visible. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem using RVM, if you're using RVM do: `$rvm 1.9.2` (or whatever ruby version you installed the rails 3 gem with).

Check the output of `$ ruby -v` when you seem to have access to rails3 and again `$ ruby -v` when you can only seem to get to v2.3.5.  If it shows different versions of ruby then you most likley are using RVM.

Answer (score 0):

@Ads If youre using RVM and you install rails using sudo like so

```
$ [sudo] gem install rails --version 3.0.3
```

youre doing it wrong. RVM depends on you using a ruby distro that was installed by RVM into your user directory. If youre using sudo, youre installing rails gem into your system-wide ruby.

So check that youre using the right ruby version by doing 'rvm info' and then do your 'gem install rails --version 3.0.3' without sudo