# Rails is broken after upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-11.04

I'm still relatively new to Rails and Ruby - and after upgrading to the new version of Ubuntu (11.04), my rails installation is not working correctly. I've tried updating Rails, and updating the versions I have installed using RVM, none of which worked.

Here is the terminal output:

```
 /usr/share/rails-ruby1.8/railties/lib/rails_generator/options.rb:32:in `default_options': undefined    method `write_inheritable_attribute' for Rails::Generator::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/share/rails-ruby1.8/railties/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:90:in `<class:Base>'
    from /usr/share/rails-ruby1.8/railties/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:85:in `<module:Generator>'
    from /usr/share/rails-ruby1.8/railties/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:48:in `<module:Rails>'
    from /usr/share/rails-ruby1.8/railties/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/alec/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/alec/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/share/rails-ruby1.8/railties/lib/rails_generator.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/share/rails-ruby1.8/railties/bin/rails:14:in `<main>'
```

From that, I tried updating railties specifically, but that didn't work either. The output hasn't changed since I first received the error.

Comment: Did upgrading Ubuntu also upgrade your ruby version? Check ruby -v to make sure you're not trying to use rails-ruby1.8 with ruby 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that rails reverted back to 2.3.5. I had to uninstall rails and set up a gemset as described here: [Every time I close terminal rails defaults back to 2.3.5 from 3.0.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824139/every-time-i-close-terminal-rails-defaults-back-to-2-3-5-from-3-0-3/4824630#4824630)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you take a look at RVM.  It is by far the best way to manage installations of Ruby and Rails on the *NIX platforms.

Comment: I was using RVM - somehow after updating the system was reverting back to the system install of 2.3.5 instead of using my RVM installations, even after I sudo'ed rvm to use otherwise.