# Rails - migration suddenly doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Rails app suddenly stopped to work when i try to run migration. For example:

```
$ rails generate migration AddBalanceToUsers balance:float
/Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/../lib/rails_generator/options.rb:32:in `default_options': undefined method `write_inheritable_attribute' for Rails::Generator::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/../lib/rails_generator/base.rb:90
    from /Users/serg/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Users/serg/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/../lib/rails_generator.rb:34
    from /Users/serg/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Users/serg/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/rails:14
    from /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-head/bin/rails:19:in `load'
    from /Users/serg/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-head/bin/rails:19
```

I use

```
ree 1.8.7
rails 2.3.5 (but i also have rails 3.2.3)
RVM
OS X Lion
```

Comment: Check Similar issue:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849332/rails-is-broken-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-11-04

Comment: @Shamithc I tried: 'gem uninstall rails' and then 'gem install rails -v=2.3.5' but i still have such problem

Comment: You can update rails to 2.3.8 and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i founded solution. In **rails 2** we should generate migration via other way:

```
$ script/generate migration AddBalanceToUsers balance:float
```

**script/generate** is the key.

Hope it'll help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by following below steps :-

(1) First I checked by running ‘gem environment’

(2) Then I located the rails executable by :-
abc@ubuntu:~$ locate rails |grep -e "bin/rails$"
/home/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/bin/rails
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/bin/rails

(3) I appended the path to ~/.bashrc by :-
abc@ubuntu:~$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-0/gems/railties-.2.1/bin' >> ~/.bashrc

(4) Reload the ~/.bashrc file:-
abc@ubuntu:~$ . ~/.bashrc

And then when I ran the rails command, it created a new sample app perfectly :-)