# How to set default rails version for a project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed two different rails versions in my system (Fedora).

```
gem list -d rails
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (3.0.5, 1.2.1)
    Author: David Heinemeier Hansson
    Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/rails
    Homepage: http://www.rubyonrails.org
    Installed at (3.0.5): /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
                 (1.2.1): /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

    Full-stack web application framework.
```

When i try to create the project like following way ("http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2008/03/12/using-multiple-versions-of-rails/")

```
rails 1.2.1 myproject
```

But, it's not working. So, i checked

```
rails -v
Rails 3.0.5
```

So, can you help me, how to create the project with older version and newer version. Is there any way to set the particular rails version as default?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To use an older version than the latest you have installed, just wrap the version number in underscores:

`rails _1.2.1_ myproject`

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to set this as a system wide default. You could use a bash alias or similar, e.g. `alias rails="rails _1.2.1_"`.

Comment: thanks @matkins. Can you do one more favor for me. I have a one project in rails 1.2.1 version. now, i have additionally installed the new rails version, 3.0.0. So, when i try to run my project project (build by 1.2.1) script/server, it doesn't run. Is it right way to run when the two rails version installed in my system. the error is "127.0.0.1 - - [27/May/2011:11:05:21 IST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 309"

Comment: Can you give more details about the error? It might be worth asking another question about this as it seems to be a different issue.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get matkins' answer to work via RailsInstaller on Windows 7, so I thought I'd post my solution for someone else to benefit from: (I don't have the reputation to offer this as a comment so I'm adding a new answer)

```
c:\>rails -v
Rails 4.0.0

c:\>rails _3.2.8_ app1 &REM This is going to bug out
```

Instead, I found this works:

```
c:\>rails _3.2.8_ new app1 &REM This will work
```

Comment: Yes.. Your answer is also correct.. But you were pointed rails 3 version and markins were pointed rails < *2 version.. Hopefully both will work.

Answer (score 3):

The URL you posted solves your problem - you simply forgot the underscores.

```
varar:~ mr$ gem list rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (3.1.0.rc1, 3.1.0.beta1, 3.0.3, 3.0.1)
varar:~ mr$ rails _3.0.1_ -v
Rails 3.0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Shaun mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824139/every-time-i-close-terminal-rails-defaults-back-to-2-3-5-from-3-0-3), you can use multiple versions of Rails and Ruby in same time!
For using an specific version of ruby:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

Switch `--default` is used for setting this version as Ruby default version.
For using an specific Rails and Ruby version:

```
rvm gemset create rails-3.2.3
rvm use 1.9.3@rails-3.2.3 --default
gem install rails
```

First line creates a gemset and related folder under `/home/username/.rvm/gems/`
Second line use that gemset as default one
Third line install specified version in gemset (Rails 3.2.3) on related folder.

This is my `gems` folder's contents:

```
cache  ruby-1.9.3-p194  ruby-1.9.3-p194@global  ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.3
```

Initial folder is `ruby-1.9.3-p194@global`. Therefore  for backing to previous state, just run:

```
rvm use 1.9.3@global
```

and you can see previous Rails and Ruby versions :)

Good luck

Comment: Everything worked good until I tried to install rails specific version (3.2.6). gem installs version 4.0.0, even when I specify the rails version, any comment?

Comment: To install rails 3.2.6 used `gem install rails -v 3.2.6`

Comment: Make sure you used `rvm` to set correct `gemset` as active one. (and not installed it on other `gemset`). If problem exists, so you can start a new Question.

Answer (score 1):

To create a project with the specific rails version use the below command:
similar to [matkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265985/matkins) suggested

```
rails _5.0.7.2_ new <project_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/environment.rb` file, place this at the beginning for the old version:

`RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '1.2.1'`

or this for the new version:

`RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '3.0.5'`

Answer (score -1):

here is a general format example. feel free to modify as needed

```
    rvm use ruby-2.1.0@rails4.2
```

Answer (score -3):

You first installed a rvm(rails version management) 
then type.
rvm 1.2.1

Comment: This is incorrect. RVM stands for Ruby Version Manager and has nothing to do with rails itself.