# rails s command creating new project and gem rails 3 and rails -v conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, webrick

`rails s`

command creating new project inside project directory instead of starting server.

I installed rails in my system but it is showing unexpected behavior, as creating project instead of starting server.

I see in my system by running gem list | grep rails command it shows rails 3.2.11 but when I see using rails -v then it shows rails 2.3.11

SO on running rails s it picks rails 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Gosavi and @boulder

Your solutions are also worthy, but my prbolem was resolved doing this

My app was poiniting to default gemset so I created new gemset for my app

To create new gemset

```
rvm --rvmrc --create 1.9.3@project_name
```

To list avaliable gemsets:

```
rvm gemset list
```

Answer (score 7):

Please check Your version of rails. It is definitely < 3.

So use `ruby script/server` instead of rails s.

Comment: This did not worked, as I see in my system by running gem list | grep rails command it shows rails 3.2.11 but when I see using rails -v then it shows rails 2.3.11

Comment: you are searching through gem file. but actual version set to rails 2.3.11 because of which above command not works

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148308/set-rails-version-as-default

Answer (score 0):

You will be running the first version of rails that is found in your PATH. You can always [change your path environment variable](http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) so it finds rails 3.2.11 first, but if you are trying to manage several versions of rails/ruby on your system I recommend you use [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or rbenv.