# Rails Version Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have an app and in that app's `Gemfile` it is specified that Rails -v 3.2.12 should be used, but when I run '`rails -v`' from within that app's directory, '`Rails 2.3.14`' is outputted. Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

UPDATE:

I am now using `rvm`.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` or `bundle update`?

Comment: Are you using rvm, rbenv, etc? If no, how are you setting which Ruby/gemset/etc you're using?

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire bundle install

Comment: @DaveNewton I am not. I just installed ruby, bundler, rails and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Try running with:

```
bundle exec rails -v
```

Are you using rbenv or similar? Either way, what is probably happening is you have an old version of rails installed. If you don't need it:

```
 gem uninstall rails -v 2.3.14
```

then install bundler and

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Okay, so 'bundle exec rails -v' returns the correct version. And I am not--should I be? (This is my first time setting up rails on Ubuntu, but I've used rvm in the past--is it similar?) Also, I tried to uninstall the gem and received the error 'gem 'rails' is not installed'.

Comment: So if that returns the right version, what is the issue? Start your server with bundle exec rails s

Comment: Ahhh, I hadn't thought of thought. I guess the issue was that I was using 'rails s' to start the server and that was running 2.3.14.

Comment: Right, so did bundle exec rails s work for you then? Obviously you'd need bundle exec rails c etc for the console. Most people alias it to 'be' by the way. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just installed `rvm` and then followed the instructions at the following link:

[How to set default rails version for a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148308/set-rails-version-as-default)