# Can I execute rails new command without specifying the patch version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanna to run `rails new` like this: `rails _5.0.x_ new`. Is it possible accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that command without patch number like this:
`rails _4.2_ new project_name`

I checked it on my machine. I had rails 4.2.0 and 4.2.5. With that command it created the project with rails 4.2.0

Comment: Thanks, actually I wanted to get the most upgraded version in 5.0, but it does not make sense because I have to install the gem before.

Comment: Glad to help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

To use an older version than the latest you have installed, just wrap the version number in underscores:

```
rails _1.2.1_ myproject
```

see also [How to set default rails version for a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148308/how-to-set-default-rails-version-for-a-project)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use RVM or any Ruby version manager?

EDIT:

My bad, actually, you were talking about rails. So, to answer your question, you can do `rails _5.0.x_ new`.

You can find more details [on this post](http://craiccomputing.blogspot.jp/2008/06/using-older-versions-of-rails.html) and [this one](http://rubybook.ca/2008/08/06/downgrade-older-version-rails/).

Comment: Yes, I use RVM and rbenv.

Comment: Error: can't find gem railties (= 5.0.x)
rails -v => Rails 5.0.1